# Implementing a white background on SVG text (similar to a label)

Tags: html, svg

Is there a way to use svg text and achieve a white background like that in a label. For example, in the picture [here](http://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-1e984666a9a2bb435cce96671e0237ea), the text under the nodes have a white background attach to them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can draw it by creating a rectangle behind the text, with attribute `fill="white"`

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to not use rectangles because that would require me to measure the width of the text. (I need to do this for a lot of text).